# Use template tag return value for conditional logic in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a template tag that returns True or False.
For example:

```
@register.simple_tag
def is_home(context):
   if homepage:
       return True
   else:
       return False
```

I want to use this tag to change an icon in the template:

```
{% if is_home %}
  <svg data-src="{% static 'images/cart_white.svg' %}" width="35" height="30"/>
{% else %}
   <svg data-src="{% static 'images/cart.svg' %}" width="35" height="30"/>
{% endif %}
```

However the template tag is not called like this.

Only if I call it like this: {% is_home %} it works but I cannot use the result for the conditional.

Any idea how can I use the result for logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `simple_tag` can also be used to [set a variable in the context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags):

```
{% is_home as is_home %}
{% if is_home %} {# now testing the `is_home` var #}
  <svg data-src="{% static 'images/cart_white.svg' %}" width="35" height="30"/>
{% else %}
   <svg data-src="{% static 'images/cart.svg' %}" width="35" height="30"/>
{% endif %}
```